# Setup the master branches of two maven git projects in Eclipse(STS)

Tags: java, git, eclipse, m2eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite 4.5.1 based on Eclipse Platform 4.14.
I have two maven projects in their respective master git branches.
The local structure folder structure template is: `<root folder>\<project>\<branch>`
So for the two projects I have:
`<root folder>\<project 1>\master\pom.xml
<root folder>\<project 2>\master\pom.xml`

When I import project 1, STS creates a project named `master`. Even if I change the name in the .project file, STS keeps displaying `master` and it is impossible to import project 2 as STS(Eclipse) complains that there is already a project named `master`.

So my question is how can I overcome this?

I am trying to avoid changing the directory naming convention to `<root folder>\<project>-<branch>\`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good idea to have the `pom.xml` located under the `<project-1>` instead of something in between there. That should allow the Maven Integration for Eclipse to import the projects nicely.

Where you insert the git branch name into the directory structure above that `<project-1>/pom.xml` structure doesn't matter that much, I think. You could either go with `<root>/master/<project-1>/pom.xml` or `master/<root>/<project-1>/pom.xml`.

Depending on how you work with git and the different branches, having different root directories for the different branches checked out might also make sense, but that depends.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, the projects are in different git repositories, so this structure is not suitable (every master is in a separate git repo).

Comment: Usually the branch name is not part of a folder structure inside of the git repo, therefore I don't understand why you are not able to checkout each individual project into the proposed directory structure.